# Usage of Initilizer list with default keyword

Tags: c++, initialization-list

Why I cannot use *default* keyword after initialization list

```
class classA
{
    int num;
public:
    classA():num(3) = default;
};
```

Comment: Either you implement your own constructor, or you use the compiler default constructor. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: The initializer list is part of the *definition* of the constructor. You can only have *one* definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`= default` provides a definition of the constructor. Note that it doesn't provide the *body,* it provides a *definition.* The definition of a constructor includes both the mem-initialiser-list and the body. So if you want your own mem-initialiser-list, you must provide the entire definition yourself.

Also note that there is zero problem with doing that. Just write `{}` instead of `= default`. A default constructor defined with `= default` performs exactly the same operations as one defined with `{}`.

The only difference between these is that a constructor defined with `= default` right at its declaration is not considered user-provided and thus allows the class to be a trivial class. But since you want something non-trivial to happen in the constructor, you get exactly what you want by using `{}`.

Comment: I think you meant `default` in the last paragraph, not `delete`.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative solution:

```
class classA
{
    int num = 3;

public:
    classA() = default;
};
```

Comment: This does little to answer the "why" question, I'm afraid.